# Box.com creating folder for record failing

Tags: trigger, callout, sandbox

i'm encountering a wierd behavior in my box.com integration for salesforce.

Here's the code.

```
@future (callout=true)
public static void createFolder(Id id)
{   
     //Instantiate the Toolkit object
    box.Toolkit boxToolkit = new box.Toolkit();
    //get Folderid for record Id
    String folderId = boxToolkit.createFolderForRecordId(id, null, true);
    String parentFolderId=boxToolkit.getFolderIdByRecordId(id);
    System.Debug('folder ID ' + parentFolderId);
    if(folderId == null){
        System.Debug(boxToolkit.mostRecentError );
    }
}
```

When I call this from anonymous execute in the dev console, the code executes successfully and a folder is created and it prints the parent folder ID.

However, when i execute this code from the afterInsert trigger of an opportunity object. I get the mostRecentError of:

> 21:39:16:452 USER_DEBUG [18]|DEBUG|Unable to create folder for record
>   id 0061100000CwEAZAA3 - Details: Unable to use default credentials to
>   make a callout to box (maybe this is in a trigger or constructor):

This is just bizarre because I specified `callout=true` in the static function. Any ideas?

Comment: (1) when you execute through the trigger, are you the same running user as when you did the execute anonymous? (2) What version is the trigger at?  (3) As an aside, your future method is not bulkified so when the trigger executes on a batch of 200 records, you'll blow up async callout governor limits. Consider chained queuables.

Comment: Did you run the destructor? `boxToolkit.commitChanges();`